# Is virtual environment in Django created in one Operating System work in another Operating System?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I'm a beginner in web programming. I've been working on a Django project along with my teammates. I'm using Mac and he's using Ubuntu.

I want to know if the virtual environment created in my system will work on his machine if I sent him mine. Is virtual environment in Django OS specific?

Comment: I don't think venv created in one OS will work on another. You have to use create another one.

Comment: [virtualenvs aren't relocatable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+relocatable). They're development tools but not distribution/deployment tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtual environments are OS-specific.  This is because python packages can use native code that would have to be compiled on different OSes.  That said, virtual environments were created to make sharing code among developers on different environments easy!  The way you do it is by including a file called `requirements.txt` in your project.  As part of getting started on this project, every developer should do the following:

```
python -m venv env  # you only have to do this line once
source env/bin/activate  # you have to do this line every time
pip install -r requirements.txt
```